# Calling private function from public function within a module result in CompileError

Tags: elixir

I have defined the following functions inside a main module. From function `movie_title` a call to `id_title` is made but is throwing compilation error

```
defp id_title(title) do
    {k, v} = title
    with {:ok, primary} = Map.fetch(v, "primary"),
         {:ok, movie_title} = Map.fetch(primary, "title"),
         do: %{k=> movie_title} 
  end  

  def movie_titles(map) do
    titles = Map.get(map, "titles")
    Enum.map(titles, id_title)
  end
```

Error

```
== Compilation error in file lib/moviematch.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/moviematch.ex:48: undefined function id_title/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

Comment: As well as the linked post, there's another error in your code: you didn't pass the map to `Map.get("titles")`. A better way would be to pattern match it in the function definition: `def movie_titles(%{"titles" => titles})`

Comment: corrected that.